# Tikz package - How to write a text over a segment determined by the two points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a line composed from 6 points: A,B,C,D,E,F. I know how to create this points in tikz package but I don't know how to write a text over the segment determined by the points A and B, and then a text over the segment determined by the points B and C, and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: Without your line the meaning of "over"is completely unclear. What does it mean if the line forms a hexagon?

Comment: 6 colinear points determined 5 segments. For each segment I want to write a text over it.

Comment: Why not writing 5 commands, one text/node per line? It's easier than creating one line.

Comment: @Alenanno For me is ok to write one text/node per line, but I don't know how to it.. I know just to create a line determined by 6 colinear points

Comment: `\draw (A) -- node[above] {path label} (B); as one possibilities. For this you also can employ library `quotes`. If you provide MWE, the help can be better ...

Comment: Well, then, could you provide code that creates the lines you want to, without the text?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Very basic (and limited,one without sophisticated `\foreach` usage, one with `\foreach`)

The key point is to define coordinates and a `\node (...) at ($(Foo)!.5!(Foobar)$) {...}`, meaning to place the node between two coordinates named `(Foo)` and `(Foobar)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,5} {
    \coordinate (A\x) at (\x,0);
    \draw[fill=red] (A\x) circle(2pt);
  }
  \draw (A0) -- (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- (A5);
  \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$A$] (A00) at ($(A0)!.5!(A1)$) {};
  \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$B$] (A10) at ($(A1)!.5!(A2)$) {};
  \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$C$] (A20) at ($(A2)!.5!(A3)$) {};
  \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$D$] (A30) at ($(A3)!.5!(A4)$) {};
  \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$E$] (A40) at ($(A4)!.5!(A5)$) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,9} {%
    \coordinate (A\x) at (\x,0);
    \draw[fill=black,black] (A\x) circle(2pt);
  }
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/A,1/B,2/C,3/D,4/E,5/F,6/G,7/H,8/I} {%
    \draw (A\x) -- (A\the\numexpr\x+1);
    \node[inner sep=2pt,label=above:$\y$] (A\x 0) at ($(A\x)!.5!(A\the\numexpr\x+1)$) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let assume, that coordinates of start and end of segments are known and has names `A`, `B`, ... etc and that segments are presented with lines between mentioned coordinates. Text over lines you can write on many way. Beside on way described in Christian Hupfer, there are other, to my opinion simpler possibilities (as I indicate in my comment above:

- `\draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,% determine point on the middle between A and B
                        above, % text will appear above line
                        ] {text};`
- the same result gives `\draw (A) -- node[above] {text};`
- with help of TikZ library `quotes` -- it had to be loaded in document preamble with `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}` -- the same result you can be obtain with `\draw (A) to ["text"] (B);` . Using this option usually to TikZ picture is added option `auto`, for example like this `\begin{tikzpicture}[auto] ... \end{tikzpicutre}`.
- if the line is not horizontal aligned, than the option `sloped` in node align text with line: `\draw (A) -- node[above,sloped] {text};` or similarly with quotes: `\draw (A) to [sloped,"text"] (B);`
- if the text should be between coordinates, than `quotes` (which is intended to write labels on path) doesn't come to account. With node you can this positioning achieve with `\draw (A) -- node[fill=white] {text};`, where `fill=white` cover part of line, where is placed text.

The forms of node is the best to determine wits node style.  Of course, it is highly recommendable to read TikZ manual. The basic can be found in chapter 17: Nodes and Edges.